# SCCM 2007 sp2 Client installation issue

Tags: sccm

I'm having a problem with some users in my network with SCCM client, some computers are approved and having the client and some other users are having N/A and client as NO although the client is installed but in the action menu I see only 2 actions.

Any advice would be so much appreciated.

Thanks & best regards,
Ahmad.

Answer (score 0):

Check the boundaries that you have set for site.  Are the clients showing as N/A within subnets that have been specified in your SCCM boundaries?

If you are using client push, check the ccm.log on the server to see why the installations are not working.

How are you verifying that the client is installed?  You may also need to update the collection you are using to view the clients.